# A multiple choice question on Artinian modules

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity, $M$ an $R$-module and $N$ is a submodule of $M$. Which of the following statements true?
>
> 1. If every submodule of $M$ is Artinian, then $M$ is Artinian.
> 2. If $M/N$ is Artinian, then $M$ is Artinian.
> 3. If $N$ is Artinian, then $M/N$ is Artinian.

Clearly (1) is true. (2) is false because consider the $\mathbb{Z}$-module $\mathbb{Q}$. But (3)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For (3): What if you take $N = 0$ and $M = \Bbb{Z}$?